# Visual Studio Code won't let me debug a specific code I wrote

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a task in college. I'm trying to debug a program, but Visual Studio Code won't let me do it, instead it says: "Waiting for the debugger to disconnect..." and the problem is only with the specific code.
Please help me solve it, 'cause I was trying to find the problem in my code all day and finally decided to ask here.
Thanks in advance!

```js
function summerOutfit(input){
    let degrees = Number(input.shift())
    let dayType = input.shift()

    var outfit;
    var shoes;

    if (degrees >= 10 && degrees <= 18){
        if (dayType == 'Morning'){
            outfit = 'Sweatshirt';
            shoes = 'Sneakers';
        } else if (dayType == 'Afternoon'){
            outfit = 'Shirt';
            shoes = 'Moccasins';
        } else if (dayType == 'Evening'){
        outfit = 'Shirt';
        shoes = 'Moccasins';
        }
    } else if (degrees > 18 && degrees <= 24){
        if (dayType == 'Morning'){
            outfit = 'Shirt';
            shoes = 'Moccasins';
        } else if (dayType == 'Afternoon'){
            outfit = 'T-Shirt';
            shoes = 'Sandals';
        } else if (dayType == 'Evening'){
            outfit = 'Shirt';
            shoes = 'Moccasins';
        }
    } else if (degrees >= 25){
       if (dayType == 'Morning'){
            outfit = 'T-shirt';
            shoes = 'Sandals';
        } else if (dayType == 'Afternoon'){
            outfit = 'Swim Suit';
            shoes = 'Barefoot';
        } else if (dayType == 'Evening'){
            outfit = 'Shirt';
            shoes = 'Moccasins';
        }
    }

console.log(`It's ${degrees} degrees, get your ${outfit} and ${shoes}.`);

}

summerOutfit[16,'Morning']
```

Comment: You're best off getting the debugger working, as someone could help you solve this problem, but the debugger will help you in all future problems. Can you share your debugger config setup? Also, how are you running this code, via the node command? VSCode docs on setting up the Debugger. These can be hard to parse, so if you give me more info I can help you.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the function is not being called because the last line does not call a function. Add parentheses so that the array is passed as an argument:

`summerOutfit([16,'Morning'])`

When i ran with with the parentheses I got this output:

`It's 16 degrees, get your Sweatshirt and Sneakers.`

Not having the parentheses you are asking for the the value of the summerOutfit array at 16, 'Morning' which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Function calls use `()` not `[]` you might be confused because your function argument is an array

```js
function summerOutfit(input) {
  let degrees = Number(input.shift());
  let dayType = input.shift();

  var outfit;
  var shoes;

  if (degrees >= 10 && degrees <= 18) {
    if (dayType == 'Morning') {
      outfit = 'Sweatshirt';
      shoes = 'Sneakers';
    } else if (dayType == 'Afternoon') {
      outfit = 'Shirt';
      shoes = 'Moccasins';
    } else if (dayType == 'Evening') {
      outfit = 'Shirt';
      shoes = 'Moccasins';
    }
  } else if (degrees > 18 && degrees <= 24) {
    if (dayType == 'Morning') {
      outfit = 'Shirt';
      shoes = 'Moccasins';
    } else if (dayType == 'Afternoon') {
      outfit = 'T-Shirt';
      shoes = 'Sandals';
    } else if (dayType == 'Evening') {
      outfit = 'Shirt';
      shoes = 'Moccasins';
    }
  } else if (degrees >= 25) {
    if (dayType == 'Morning') {
      outfit = 'T-shirt';
      shoes = 'Sandals';
    } else if (dayType == 'Afternoon') {
      outfit = 'Swim Suit';
      shoes = 'Barefoot';
    } else if (dayType == 'Evening') {
      outfit = 'Shirt';
      shoes = 'Moccasins';
    }
  }

  console.log(`It's ${degrees} degrees, get your ${outfit} and ${shoes}.`);
}

summerOutfit([16, 'Morning']);
```